# NEST for ElasticSearch - JSONSerializationException when retrieving data

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, json.net, nest

I am using the [NEST API](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST) (v0.12.0.0) to interface with an ElasticSearch (v1.0.1) index and I just started receiving a JsonSerializationException when retrieving my data. I'm not sure if this is a NEST issue or otherwise, but it just randomly started happening and we haven't made any major changes to our implementation or infrastructure.

I am attempting to retrieve the Ids of my data (stored as a Guid) with a typed Search<>() and I am getting an exception when the data is processed by JSON.NET.

```
client.Search<ESEventItem>(s => 
          s.Index("dev-events004")
          .Fields(f => f.Id).Size(100000)
          .Type("event").MatchAll()).Documents.ToList()
```

[image: JsonSerializationException]

Running this same query manually in Sense produces no noticeable issues:

```
POST /dev-events004/event/_search
{
  "size": 100000,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": [
    "id"
  ]
}
```

---

```
{
   "took": 2088,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 19257,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "dev-events004",
            "_type": "event",
            "_id": "670a1055-cbe3-480e-b807-a2b500f9dfb3",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "id": [
                  "670a1055-cbe3-480e-b807-a2b500f9dfb3"
               ]
            }
         },
         /* ... additional results ... */
      ]
   }
}
```

---

If I perform a raw, untyped query `Fields(new[] { "Id" })` it does not throw an exception. Likewise, if I return the whole ESEventItem object, rather than just the Id fields, it also works without an exception.

---

To the NEST developer: this question is mirrored as an [issue on the github project](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues/484).

Comment: When I update NEST to the latest version from the sources I do not get this issue, but that version is not yet stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due the fact that elasticsearch 1.0 changed how fields are returned. The upcomming NEST 1.0 will support this.